# Alternate for SafeAgainstScript attribute in sharepoint 2007?

Tags: 2007

How can we use SafeAgainstScript attribute in sharepoint 2007 ? Is there any alternate for that in sharepoint 2007 ?

Comment: You have tagged the question with SharePoint Online, but seeking an answer for 2007. Can you please re-tag the question?